# Invoke AWS lambda function from slack channel using AWS Chatbot - automate it, without user intervention

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, slack-api, aws-chatbot

I've a slack workflow setup which will take approval in different channel and invoke AWS lambda from another private channel to restrict the access to AWS chatbot. But after the lambda is invoked, Chatbot is again asking for confirmation which requires some one to manually approve it again. Is there any way to bypass this.?
[image]

*The aim is to automate this and remove user intervention, any workaround is appreciated*

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of AWS Bot states that :

 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/running-aws-commands-from-slack-using-aws-chatbot/

> **Invoke a Lambda function from Slack** To trigger a workflow or a runbook
> from Slack, you can invoke a Lambda function by running @aws lambda
> invoke FUNCTION_NAME. ***AWS Chatbot will ask for a confirmation.***

Comment: I was wondering if we can do it without confirmation or may be any work around with slack workflows.? 

I've checked AWS lambda options in Chatbot, I didn't see any options for force run or such.

Comment: Since this is a proprietary AWS app, it does not offer any customization.

Comment: Any workaround to automate.? May be something similar to slack workflows..

Comment: I don't think any workflow will do. You should make a custom slack app if you really want to do this.  The app will invoke the lambda using the credentials provided OR you can also deploy custom app to a machine which have role to invoke lambda functions.

Comment: Slack workflow functionality does not cover this use case, the best way forward is probably to write your own application